# Access module attribute from within the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, attributes

I have a function and the fully qualified name is -> `pyserv.asynch.service.modules.get_result()`

It is possible that `pyserv` or other module, say `services` or `modules` is added an attribute during runtime.

It is possible that one of below is set during run-time

```
pyserv._service = "call"
services._service = "mode"
modules._service = "test"
```

And user can call the func with -> `service.modules.get_result()` or `modules.get_result()`. In such cases, I want to get "_service" value of the immediate caller module from within the get_result() method.

I tried using inspect API. But I'm only able to get the callers but not the module. Can someone suggest how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What have you tried with the inspect module?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with something like this:

```py
import inspect
def get_result():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    caller_frame = frame.f_back
    caller_mod = inspec.getmodule(caller_frame) # <--- this is the module where get_result() was called.
```